# How to Retrieve Binary image from db to view through Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show the picture in the preview after I click on edit button, but it gets a picture in binary form in the list and then passes it to ajax call through Json result after that it did not convert under ajax call.can anyone help me to sort out this problem.thanks

**JS**

```
function Edit(id) {        
    $("#submit").html("Update  Record");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/EditUser', 
        data: { userid:id},
        success: function (data) {                
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#imgPreview").show();
            $("#imageBrowes:file").html(obj.Image_ID);
            $("#targetImg").attr('src', "data:image/gif;base64,{0}", obj.ImageTbl.ImageByte);
            $("#CId").val(obj.Content_ID);
            $("#title").val(obj.Title);
            $("#desc").val(obj.Description);
            $("#type option:selected").text(obj.TypeTbl.Name);
            $("#type option:selected").val(obj.Type_ID);
            $("#fromdate").val(obj.DateFrom);
            $("#todate").val(obj.DateTo);
        },
        failure: function (responce) {
            alert.responce("Record not Found");
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int userid)
{
    ContentTbl model = db.ContentTbls.Where(x => x.Content_ID == userid).SingleOrDefault();
    var editimg = model.Image_ID;
    TempData["eimageid"] = editimg;
    string value = string.Empty;
    value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
    JsonResult json = Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;    
    return json;      
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="imgPreview" class="thumbnail" style="display:none">
    <img class="img-responsive" id="targetImg" />
    <div class="caption">
        <span id="description"></span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ClearPreview()"><iclass="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Clear</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Convert image to byte array and the convert to base64 string

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Controller:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image"),Model.FileName);
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
{
     using (var img = Image.FromStream(ms, false, true)) 
     {
        img.Save(path);
     }
}
```

In view page give src of the image when you save the image.

Answer (score 0):

Convert raw image to byte array and then to ToBase64String

```
  Convert.ToBase64String(obj.ImageTbl.ImageByte.ToArray());
```

Comment: thnks bro for your comment but it does not work under ajax cal. i got this error " Uncaught ReferenceError: Convert is not defined "

Comment: You have to use it on server side, not in ajax